# CSS animate radial gradient?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a div with a background radial gradient like this..

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, #d9affe, #a034fe 100%);
```

How do I create an animation or transition so that the center of the circle moves from 0% to 100% like this...

From:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, #d9affe, #a034fe 100%);
```

To:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, #d9affe, #a034fe 100%);
```

Many thanks